# Eliminate the elements that separates primefaces layoutUnit after generate html

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Is it possible to eliminate or edit the elements that separates primefaces layoutUnit elements (top, west, center, etc)?
These elements have id ending with
-resizer

I can't find which class do it in primefaces-3.1.1.jar.

For example, when element layoutUnit west after generate into html has the css attribute

```
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
width: 94px;
```

then the right layoutUnit after generate into html element has the css attribute

```
position: absolute;
left: 107px;
```

because between them is generated resizer element(div) with attributes

```
position: absolute;
left: 100px;
width: 6px;
```

How can I avoid this effect?

Comment: You want to get rid of the generated resizer elements?  The layoutUnit components have an attribute `resizable` that can be set to false.  Do they still appear after setting resizable to false?

Comment: Exactly, I want to get rid of the generated resizer elements. I know the layoutUnit have a attribute resizable, but when I set it to false resizer element is still appear :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use gutter attribute. Set it to zero

Comment: when use attribute gutter important is set attribute collapsible on true

Answer (score 1):

After much toiling i did this and it worked just like that.  Resizers are gone.  Add this to your css

.ui-layout-resizer, .ui-layout-resizer-north, .ui-layout-resizer-open, .ui-layout-resizer-north-open{
                height:0px !important;
            }