# Removing gutters from p:layout

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm using PrimeFaces 5.0. I'm having a trouble setting gutter in `<p:layout>`.

```
<p:layout id="templateLayout" fullPage="false">

    <p:layoutUnit id="header" position="north" size="155" gutter="0">
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit position="west" id="leftPanel" size="225" gutter="0">
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit position="east" size="200" gutter="0">
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit id="content" position="center" size="2500"
                  style="z-index: 1;" maxSize="2500" gutter="0">
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit id="footer" position="south" size="90" gutter="0">
    </p:layoutUnit>

</p:layout>
```

Event though the gutter attribute is set to 0 everywhere, the gutters between `<p:layoutUnit>` are not removed. The only gutter which is removed is between the east and the center units.

Tried to apply the following CSS alternatively.

```css
.ui-layout-unit {
    padding-top: 0 !important;
    padding-right:  0 !important;
    padding-bottom:  0 !important;
    padding-left:  0 !important;
}
```

and

```css
.ui-layout-resizer, 
.ui-layout-resizer-north, 
.ui-layout-resizer-open,
.ui-layout-resizer-north-open {
     height:0px !important;
}
```

But that did not make a difference either.

How to remove all gutters from `<p:layout>` then?

Comment: this may help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669578/eliminate-the-elements-that-separates-primefaces-layoutunit-after-generate-html

Comment: No I set all gutters to zero in addition to using the CSS class mentioned in one of the answers there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had the same problem.

What I did was using the following properties in the layoutUnit component:

```
collapsible="true" gutter="0"
```

It seems that gutter doesn't work unless you use it with collapsible.

The credit goes to the good people of Primefaces Forum:

[Layout Unit Gutter Has No Effect @PrimefacesForum](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17271&start=10)

Comment: I gave it a try, it worked. By the way, I dropped using the `<p:layout>` thing in its entirely and went towards using a plain/vanilla HTML/CSS template, since I needed a template with a sticky footer which `<p:layout>` does not support out of the box unless some tedious [hacks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23372523/1391249) are made. Thanks for the answer.